# Wget does not fetch google search results

Tags: bash, wget

I noticed when running `wget https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=foo` and similar queries, I don't get the search results, but the google homepage.

There seems to be some redirect within the google page. Does anyone know a fix to `wget` so it would work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this curl commands to pull Google query results:

```
curl -sA "Chrome" -L 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=time' -o search.html
```

For using `https` URL:

```
curl -k -sA "Chrome" -L 'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=time' -o ssearch.html
```

`-A` option sets a custom user-agent `Chrome` in request to Google.

Answer (score 7):

`#q=foo` is your hint, as that's a [fragment ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), which never gets sent to the server. I'm guessing you just took this URL from your browser URL-bar when using the live-search function. Since it is implemented with a lot of client-side magic, you cannot rely on it to work; try using Google with live search disabled instead. A URL pattern that seems to work looks like this: `http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=foo`.

However, I do notice that Google returns `403 Forbidden` when called naïvely with `wget`, indicating that they don't want that. You can easily get past it by setting some other user-agent string, but do consider all the implications before doing so on a regular basis.